# How to use gunicorn server using istio-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, gunicorn, istio

Due to limitation on gunicorn, in its documentation it suggests to use a http proxy in-front of it, one of them is Nginx http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

My question is, is there any best configuration on deploying Gunicorn behind istio-proxy (and istio ingress gateway)? Probably there is istio connection pool configuration to be customized?
The thing is without http proxy, the gunicorn only able to serve traffic at most N requests at a time, N = number of gunicorn worker processes.